# Ruby: Referencing one class from another class that has the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my specific situation I have Mongo models, but I guess that the issue is more general.

I have a model named "Map", and another one with the same name, but within a module. I need the second model to belong to the first one.

Code snippet:

```
# Ruby version: 2.1.5

# app/models/map.rb
class Map
  include Mongoid::Document
end

# app/models/base_content.rb
class BaseContent
  include Mongoid::Document
end

# app/models/content/map.rb
class Content::Map < BaseContent
  belongs_to :map, class: ::Map
end
```

What is the recommended way to do this? If I do it like in the snippet above, I get a circular dependency error.

Update:

When I use class_name: 'Map' as suggested by AJcodez, this is what I get in the console:

```
[1] pry(main)> Map
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Map
from /home/m/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
[2] pry(main)> Content::Map
=> Content::Map
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `class: ::Map` to `class_name: 'Map'` which avoids the autoloading circular dependency.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. please see the update of the question.

Comment: Works for me, did you leave in the `class:` part?

Comment: With "belongs_to :map, class_name: 'Map', class: ::Map", I get circular dependency error and I can not start the console. Without it (" belongs_to :map, class_name: 'Map' ") I get the responses that I added to the question.